# How to make welcome message for new members of the discord server on discord.js?

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, bots, dm

I know this is such a basic question, but 1. I'm new to programing in discord.js (I programmed before in HTML but this is different) 2. I'm very young (I'm a **kido** LOL)

Ok, so my question is: how do I make a function at my bot that sends a welcome message on a special channel an a DM to the person who joined saying something like "Welcome" ?

I'm asking this cuz I searched on the entire web and I didn't find something that I really understand.

P.S. I would really appreciate if you can add comments with explications.

**THANKS IN ADVANCE!**

Comment: To better understand how to write a good question and get relevant answers, please read our [Welcome Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to and [How ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) articles.

Comment: Ok, but you I said i'm a kid and my english is pretty bad cuz i'm not from England or USA... But if you could help me, it will be grate!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`guildMemberAdd`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-guildMemberAdd) event to detect when a member joins a guild, [`ChannelManager#cache`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ChannelManager?scrollTo=cache) to send a message to a certain channel, and [`GuildMember#send()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=send) to send a message to a certain member.

```js
<client>.on('guildMemberAdd', (member) => {
  // use either `.get('id')` or `.find((c) => c.name === 'name'`
  const channel = member.guild.channels.cache.get('Channel ID');
  channel.send(...); // send to a channel
  member.send(...); // dm the member
});
```

Comment: I really don't understand the first comment (// use either `.get('id')` ...). What do you mean, what should I choose and how can I use it? If I copy-paste your code I get an error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'  . It refers at the first arrow-function, or how it is called... (=>)

Comment: Your error is referring to `<client>`, which is a placeholder for your client instance. When running this code, replace `<client>` with your discord.js client. My first comment is saying you should either use [`Collection#get()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=get) or [`Collection#find()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=find)

Comment: Is there any major difference between Collection#get() and Collection#find() ?

Comment: `Collection#get()` will get an element by its key. In this case, the channel's ID. `Collection#find()` will get the first element that passes the given function.